# Replace @RenderBody in ASP MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cordova, razor, partial-views

I have a web application built on ASP MVC and AngularJS. My master page:

```
...
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="navBar">...</div>

  <section class="content-wrapper">
     @RenderBody()
  </section>

  <div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

My app works in web but now needs to work in mobile. My approach has been to use Cordova so I need separate perfectly front-end to back-end. So I have to remove any reference to razor. Then, How can I render my partial views without `@RenderBody`? Have I some misconception?

**Update:**

To use Cordova I have write a lighter app with a mobile framework, concreting kendo mobile. But the essence of this mobile app is the same. I have a master page where I render my partial views. To do this, I only know use `@RenderBody`. And here is the problem because project Cordova requires a total separation between front-end and back-end, ie, I have to remove @renderBody, do not?

Regarding about how I render partial views in my controllers here is a silly example:

```
public class MobileController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult MobileIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Settings()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. _"works in web but now needs to work in mobile"_ - OK, then add media queries (or a framework that implements those, like Bootstrap). _"My approach has been to use Cordova"_ - OK, how did you incorporate that? Do you mean you're writing a Cordova "webview" app that is supposed to display this web application? _"So I have to remove any reference to razor"_ - oh? _"How can I render my partial views"_ - well, that depends on how you render them from your controllers...

Answer (score 0):

For your web app, you can mix AngularJS with ASP.NET, just like you did.

For your native app (with Cordova), you have two solutions. The first one is to use the [inAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) and navigate to your web app. The result won't be very clean but it works. The other solution (better) is to write your app entirely in AngularJS (or other front fwk), and not use server rendering (like ASP.NET). As your app ressources (*.html, *.css, *.js) will be directly included in the native app (Cordova does that for you), you must have *ready-to-use* ressources.

Is that clear enough ?

Comment: Definitively I use second approach. I have clear that, and my mobile app is entirely wrote in angular + kendo mobile, html and css except, when I call to controller to render views, I use @renderBody because I dont´t know other way.

Comment: If you use the second approach, you can't use renderBody (because when the file will be embedded into the Cordova app, the renderBody will not work anymore). Instead, you have to return plain html file from the server, and then used client templating solution (like AngularJS provides) to _generate_ your content

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as answered ?

Comment: I was already clear that I had rewrite my app in angular. I was asking about how avoid the typical @renderBody on asp mvc web application.

Comment: Ok so now, what's your interrogation ? I don' really understand the purpose of your question if you already knew the correct answer.